# Apigee exclude enities

Tags: apigee, usergrid

I'm planning to move into Apigee/Usergrid. Current solution doesn't work best (performance) so scalability is main reason I'm thinking about Apigee/Usergrid.

Currently we allow users to ignore some content (feed entries). It works similar to what allows Facebook - you can ignore single entry (entity) or user.

I checked documentation several times, and I'm not sure if it's possible with Apigee. From what I see I would have to use Query Language to exclude such a entries

```
/users/john.doe/activities?ql=select * where NOT (actor.uuid EQ __UUID__)
```

Now, when user ignores lot of items, this Query Statement will be quite long.

Is there any possibility to handle excludes inside Apigee?

Comment: This is the only way you could do it short of writing a proxy around the API calls that supports your business logic - return all results from usergrid and filter on the API proxy.

Comment: It is best if you don't use more than about 3 parameters in any query. Much more than that may cause queries to run slowly.

Comment: Thank you guys. Those answers were helpful. Now we must re-think Usergrid usage because we got some complex queries.

Answer (score 0):

Right now this is not supported in BaaS but you can use a proxy as mentioned in the comments.